# How can I assign the property of class after deserializing the object?

Tags: c#, .net, json-deserialization

I want to populate the splitterposition after deserializing the class.

```
 public class UserProfile{
        
        public int SplitterPosition { get; set; }

        public static readonly UserProfile Default = new UserProfile();

        public const string FileName = "UserProfileSettings.json";

        public UserProfile()
        {
            SplitterPosition = 313;
        }

        public static void Load()
        {
            if (File.Exists(Path.Combine(ProfileDirectory, FileName)))
            {
                UserProfile user = RoboostSerializer.DeserializeObject<UserProfile>(File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(RoBoost.Common.FileSystemConstants.ProfileDirectory, FileName)));

                Default.SplitterPosition = user.SplitterPosition;

            }
        }

        public static void Save()
        {
           string serialized = RobotSerializer.SerializeObject(Default);

            if (File.Exists(Path.Combine(ProfileDirectory, FileName)))
            {
                File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(ProfileDirectory, FileName), serialized);
            }
        }
    }
```

calling load method like this

```
UserProfile.Load();
```

but i can't figure out how to assign the prop without resetting its values

Comment: I'd expect the static Load() to return an instance of the class, not void. Then you could set SplitterPosition for the instance. Are you sure the code for UserProfile is correct?

Comment: "but i can't figure out how to assign the prop without resetting its values" - assigning a property *is* "resetting" the value of that property; ultimately `obj.SplitterPosition` is exactly what you want here - the question, though, is: "what is `obj`?` The `Load` method does not currently return an object - it just deserializes it and drops it on the floor; should that be a `return`? Likewise, we would normally expect `Save` to take in a `UserProfile` as a parameter (or alternatively: to be an instance method and use `this` as the instance)

Comment: sorry my mistake I forgot to update the code @MarcGravell

Comment: but still it will first call the default constructor and then assign it with the value.
Am I doing anything wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the updated code, it looks like what you're really asking is:

> Can we do an in-place deserialize over an existing object, and have the serializer assign values to that object?

This question is dependent on the specific serializer being used (which we can't see), but *usually* the answer is a simple "no"; most serializers do not support this use-case (some do). It looks like you're using JSON, and neither of the two most likely JSON serializers (Newtonsoft and STJ) support in-place deserialize, AFAIK. In reality, this does not present a problem, as you can:

1. manually copy properties, as you're doing
2. do an object swap, i.e. `Whatever = user;`

This second option is *usually* preferable, because it can perform this atomically - meaning: there's never a hypothetical situation (usually involving multiple threads) where an instance is observed in a corrupt state where it has *some* values from the old/outgoing data, and *some other* values from the new/incoming data - this can be dangerous and lead to invalid operation. So, ***except for a huge caveat I'll get to in a moment***, my recommendation would be to remove the `readonly`, and just do `Default = user;`.

However (the caveat)! I am *very* concerned by:

```cs
public static readonly UserProfile Default = new UserProfile();
```

This kind of `static` usage needs to be considered *very* carefully, and is usually a bad idea. It is *broadly tolerable* in single-user applications, for example desktop GUI applications, but would be *wildly* inappropriate in a server application, for example a web server. Even in a single user application, to avoid the hybrid state problem, any usage would need to capture the instance *once only*, i.e. instead of:

```cs
Write("User: " + UserProfile.Default.Id);
Write("User: " + UserProfile.Default.Name);
```

you'd need:

```cs
var user = UserProfile.Default;
Write("User: " + user.Id);
Write("User: " + user.Name);
```

By the time you've checked that for all existing code (remembering to keep checking that for every future code change), it is *less* work to simply *pass in* the appropriate user, rather than having ambient state. It might also be *acceptable* to change this slightly to be a method rather than a property/field:

```cs
var user = UserProfile.GetDefaultUser();
Write("User: " + user.Id);
Write("User: " + user.Name);
```

The significance here being that *as a method*, it "feels" more expensive, i.e. something you shouldn't do repeatedly; it would be *less likely* to see:

```cs
Write("User: " + UserProfile.GetDefaultUser().Id);
Write("User: " + UserProfile.GetDefaultUser().Name);
```

simply because the `GetDefaultUser()` "looks" suitable expensive that most people would think to snapshot the return value once. This is *not reliable*, though - people often write obviously inefficient code, so I wouldn't rely on changing this to a method being a perfect way to prevent hybrid state.

Comment: I think you are right about using static as it is only used for some properties of application . I can do an object swap but I was instructed earlier to use static for sure. Thank you for your help @MarcGravell